# Why the use of `Function.prototype.run` inside Angular type script class is illegal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to define globally new function called `run` inside my Angular component like so:

```
Function.prototype.run = function (delay: number) {
  // some content;
};
```

... but the compiler generates an error that the `Property 'run' does not exist on type 'Function'.` If I do the same code using just plain java script and compile it using node.js it compiles without any problems.
Anybody knows why?

Comment: "*If I do the same code using just plain java script and compile it using node.js it compiles without any problems.*" there is no compilation step there. You're likely just *running* the code. TS gives you a compilation error because it *doesn't* know about that  property, thus it doesn't let you run the code. If you still force it by ignoring compilation errors, it'd work. But what you need to do is declare to TS that the property exists on the global `Function` interface. With that said, it's usually a *bad* idea to modify globals, so you can easily side-step this with a separate function.

Comment: I am just learning type script. I agree with you that its not a good programming style to defined this function globally. But for the training purpose how would I `declare to TS that the property exists on the global Function interface`. Can you give me a working example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make tsc leave you alone, just cast to `any`

```js
(Function.prototype as any).run = function (delay: number) {
  // some content;
};
```

Or create a new type

```js
type myType = Function & { run: Function };

(Function.prototype as myType).run = function (delay: number) {
  // some content;
};
```

You can also use the `Object` class to define new properties

```js
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'run', {
  value: (delay: number) => {},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not recommended to add properties to native JavaScript objects, but if you really want to do it, just leverage TypeScript's [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
declare global {
    interface Function {
        run: (delay: number) => void;
    }
}

Function.prototype.run = function (delay: number) {
  // some content;
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQLMA9iZAbwChkzkpMAuZACgBMIAbOATxpHQFsAjaASmQBeAHzIAbrmD0A3MQC%20xYhiw58AOgAOUXGF2tNEdZQJDkMTNjwEGzNh258ogkmQD0b5AGdcXFAnxIcDl5GSA)

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am using Visual Studio Code for angular component.

Comment: Could you please help. Is the code you provided, run inside angular component  as type script (.ts file) or it is just plain java script (.js file). Could that be a potential problem?

Comment: Yes I edited with the actual code you need

Comment: Are you editing using actual Visual Studio Code and it does not display an error?

Comment: yes it works in VS Code, the declaration is to set at top-level (outside the class)

Comment: I did exactly that and still `run` in `Function.prototype.run = function (delay: number) {` is underlined in red colour. I wander what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I honestly have no idea!